# trying to fetch object from a collection based on the other collection object in nodejs

Tags: node.js

**trying to fetch object from a collection based on the other collection object in nodejs**

```
router.get('/shopping-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
qryFilter = { "user_id": req.user._id };
cart.find(qryFilter, function (err, cart) {
    var productcart = [];
    console.log("cart:"+cart);
    for (i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        // console.log(cart[i].id);
        Product.find({ "_id": cart[i].id }, function (err, product) {
            productcart = product;      
        // console.log('Documents: ' + productcart);
        });
    }
    res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {
        layout: 'eshop/blank',
        usercart: cart,
        productcart: productcart,
    });
});
```

});

**product id is dependent on cart content and through for loop i am getting it but cant be usinf for loop closure after response.render please guide me with the process**

Comment: DB call is asynchronous, while for loop is synchronous in nodejs. Use promises to make call for each product. And once all promises are resolved, try rendering. Also, for each DB call for Product, you have a productcart. Not sure which one are you trying to render in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB call is asynchronous, while for loop is synchronous in nodejs. Use promises to make call for each product.

```
router.get('/shopping-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
     qryFilter = { "user_id": req.user._id };

     cart.find(qryFilter, function (err, cart) {
         var productcart = [];
         var promises = [];

         for (i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
         // console.log(cart[i].id);
            promises.push(Promise.resolve(Product.find({ "_id": cart[i].id }).lean().exec().then(function (product) {
                  productcart.push(product);      
            }));
         }
         Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
             res.render('shop/shopping-cart', {
                 layout: 'eshop/blank',
                 usercart: cart,
                 productcart: productcart,
            });
        })
    })
})
```